# How do I conviniently consume OData service from .NET code

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

Is there any best-practice approach/library for consuming OData services from .NET code? So that I do not have to mess with building query string and parse the response manually?

I envision something like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    Person person = 
       new ODataRequest<Person>()
           .EndPoint("http://server.com/personservice")
           .AddHeader("header", "value")
           .AsJson()
           .Where(p => p.Name.EndsWith("y") && p.Age > 21)
           .Skip(10)
           .Take(5)
           .Send();
}
```

Please ignore the syntax (and that I'm mixing endpoint related stuff with query related stuff), this is just to convey the idea.

The code above would be supposed to automatically build proper OData query string with $filter, $skip, etc expressions as well as parse the response.

Has a library of this kind been already built? Or I'm on my own here?:)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per Padrus' answer, the library you're looking for is definitely WCF Data Services. It has a solid code-gen experience as well as a reasonably complete LINQ provider. If you want to play with it up front with minimal investment, try out the latest betas of LINQPad (http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx), which has the WCF DS client built in. To the best of my knowledge, there isn't anything else comparable out there for .NET.

Note: WCF DS is built into Visual Studio. If you use the Add Service Reference wizard to add a reference to an OData service, you will get our DLLs. Note that if you are using VS 2012, you will get references to our NuGet packages, which you can then maintain the way you maintain all of your other NuGet dependencies. If you are using VS 2010 you should still consider adding references to the NuGet packages and using NuGet to update dependencies going forward.